# Como ordenar um array por valores?

Tags: javascript

Suponha que tenho os seguintes dados.

```
Data = [3,5,1,7,3,9,10];
```

Se eu tento usar o método sort nesse array a ordenação é feita como se os dados não fossem numéricos.

```
Data.sort()
```

Mas o tipo do dado é numérico quando rodo a seguinte função: `typeof(Data[0])`

Como fazer para o javascript ordenar os dados por valores?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Explicação:

Por padrão, a função `sort()` do javascript ordena de forma léxica o seu Array. Porém opcionalmente você pode passar uma função no parâmetro de entrada, para que ela retorne o resultado desejado.

### Sobre a função sort():

> **sort**([*sortfunction*]**)**
>
> **Descrição:** ordena um array de forma léxica por padrão, porém pode ser passado uma função para ordenação.
>
> #### Parâmetros:
>
> **sortFunction** (function) *opcional*:
>
> Uma função que retorne a ordem desejada para ser utilizada no `sort()`.

## Exemplo:

```
function sortfunction(a, b){
  return (a - b) //faz com que o array seja ordenado numericamente e de ordem crescente.
}
Data = [3,5,1,7,3,9,10];
Data.sort(sortfunction); //resultado: [1, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10]
```

## [Exemplo funcional no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4tJG/)

## [Referência](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

Se os valores forem apenas números, algo assim pode resolver:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){

    return a > b;

});
```

Neste caso estou comparando cada valor no Array com o próximo valor, estabelecendo um critério de que um seja maior que o outro e retornando a comparação. Essa função será repetida percorrendo o array até que a interação inteira retorne true.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução seria assim:

```
Data = [3,5,1,7,3,9,10];

Data.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a - b;
});

var str = "";
for (var it = 0; it < Data.length; it++) {
    str += Data[it] + ",";
}

alert(str);
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zA9ZB/1/)

O que acontece é que a funcção `sort` aceita ser chamada com um parâmetro que é uma função de comparação.

### [Documentação do `sort` na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Apenas uma função como parâmetro do método `sort()` retornando `a-b` resolveria.

Comment: Pois é, eu já editei! Acabei descobrindo isso também, lá na documentação da MDN.