# Utilizando o método sort()

Tags: javascript, classificação

Pessoal tenho esse seguinte código js:

```
var livro = {
   ISBN : '978-85-7522-347-5',
   titulo : 'Aprendendo a Desenvolver Aplicações Web',
   preco : 83.00,
   autor : 'Semmy Purewal'
};
```

E preciso escrever uma expressão sort() para ordenar o vetor livros de acordo com o preço, de modo decrescente. Alguém sabe como eu devo proceder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Com [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp), crie uma função de comparação o objeto criado dentro desse array comparando o ***campo*** `preco`.

***Exemplo:***

```js
livro0 = {
   ISBN : '978-85-7522-347-0',
   titulo : 'Stackoverflow',
   preco : 15.00,
   autor : 'Stack'
};

livro1 = {
   ISBN : '978-85-7522-347-5',
   titulo : 'Aprendendo a Desenvolver Aplicações Web',
   preco : 83.00,
   autor : 'Semmy Purewal'
};

livro2 = {
   ISBN : '978-85-7522-347-1',
   titulo : 'Aplicações Web',
   preco : 80.00,
   autor : 'Samuray'
};

livros = [];

livros.push(livro0);
livros.push(livro1);
livros.push(livro2);

//resultado antes da comparação
console.log(livros);

//função responsável pela ordernação.
livros.sort(function(a, b)
{
 return b.preco - a.preco;
});

//resultado após a comparação 
console.log(livros);
```

**Comparação para ordem de: maior preço para o menor preço.**

```
livros.sort(function(a, b)
{
        return b.preco - a.preco;
});
```

**Comparação para ordem de: menor preço para o maior preço.**

```
livros.sort(function(a, b)
{
        return a.preco - b.preco;
});
```

***Referencias:***

- [Problema ao ordenar um array com sort()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118475/46523)
- [Como jogar itens com um valor especifico para o inicio de um array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42461/46523)
- [Como ordenar um array por valores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9913/46523)
- [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Valeu pessoal, salvaram aqui, obrigado!!!!